# what does objectForKey do in objective c/iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

am very new to programming and iphone programming? I have learned objective c.. so my question is doesn objectForKey in this program in the following address:

http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

thank you,

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore, it redirects to somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be "that guy", but the answer to your question (and the answers to others like it) can easily be found in Apple's documentation.

You even added the tag "nsdictionary", but did not look at the documentation, which is interesting.

Anyway,

-[NSDictionary objectForKey:] "Returns the value associated with a given key." [[source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)]

For more information on hash tables/maps/dictionaries in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 2):

`objectForKey` returns data for a specific key.  So if I have the word "english" stored in the key "language" if I use `NSString *string = [myDic objectForKey:language];` I'll get "english"

Answer (score 0):

objectForKey will retrieve an object from a dictionary of objects by it's "name". Think of it as a storage of name<->object associations. It is different from array for example ans solves different problem.